# How to make android application process as higher priority from code

Tags: android, android-activity

When application is going to background from foreground, many applications are use like chat messenger, camera etc. and then my application comes to foreground, on that time, all activity of application has been recreated due to low memory reason, my all data are losing when activity is recreating.

As per my development experience, for fix this issue, we have to save all data in local memory like shared preference or in file and then activity will recreate and restore all data at activity as per requirement. Second option for fix this issue, if I'll mark my application process as higher priority then activity will not be destroyed.

Any one can help for mark my application process id as high priority in all application stack list.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: i think, no need to alter the priority.follow activity life cycle and moveout your code from onResume() method.

Comment: @SRam Thanks for your reply. but this is not possible because application is very large and every activity have more complicated data in oncreate, and onresume method with multiple background services and threads. so can't able to manage drafting feature to like save all data in local memory and then restore all data when application will come in foreground. So please suggest me another way for cast out this issue.

Comment: Sir avoid reloading of the view while you comes from background to foreground..

Comment: OR you can write yours text on Text file and retrive from there on every reloading of data..

Comment: Yes. most form data is storing in serialized formatted in text file. but due to long route for data traveling and data objects manipulation between activities, and most of activities have more then 6k line of code so can't able to manage every parameters at every time of restoring. So please suggest me another best approach.

Answer (score 1):

setting the following properties to the only Acivity in AndroidManifest solves the problem. However I have to test it because it could have problems that I don't know:

android:launchMode="singleTask"
   android:taskAffinity=""
   android:excludeFromRecents="true"

You just have to go to the AndroidManifest.xml and inside or in your activities labels, you have to type this line of code :

android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"

Comment: Thanks for your reply. but don't need android:excludeFromRecents="true" because should have to display app in quick link and I am using " android:launchMode="singleTop" " not "singleTask" launch mode. because in single task, app will not start from it's previous state. so I am using single top launch mode.